# Rails: tumblr_client gem works in console, not in app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tumblr

I'm new to Rails and have been writing a simple app to post to Tumblr. I got all my oauth stuff working, and decided to use the [tumblr_client](https://github.com/tumblr/tumblr_client) gem to facilitate posting. I can get it to post just fine through the console, but the same code does not do anything in the controller. It doesn't throw any errors, it just does nothing. Any suggestions? (I censored the blog with {blogname}, but it is correct in my code)

```
def post
  @user = Tumblog.find_by_user_id(5)
  @client = Tumblr::Client.new(:consumer_key => @key, :consumer_secret => @secret, :oauth_token => @user.oauth_token, :oauth_token_secret => @user.oauth_secret)
  @client.text("{blogname}.tumblr.com", :body => "test", :state => "draft")
  redirect_to "http://www.tumblr.com/blog/{blogname}/drafts"
end
```

Comment: Are you sure your code is being called?
Can you capture the output of the call to `@client.text`?

Comment: I was actually in the process of writing back when I decided to try something. It seems I had a conflict with the name of my instance variable. I changed it to "@clients" and it worked! Any insight you can provide as to why this can happen would be very helpful. Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it was a conflict with my instance variable name. Changed `@client` to `@clients` and it worked just fine.